# Display color goes haywire when resuming from lock screen

Tags: unity, suspend, 14.10

Resuming the computer from locked screen sometimes ends up distorting the display.

It happens randomly and restarting the computer is one workaround for it.

I tried this : ALT+F2 ,then type “unity”. Didn't solve the problem.

[image: color distorted in ubuntu]

The issue does not appear on screen shots. I took a picture with my mobile to 
get this.

I am using X.org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati.

Any idea why might be going wrong?

UPDATE: Changed the graphic driver to use proprietary driver. Hope it solves the problem. [It didn't]

UPDATE2: Found another work around. Suspend the computer and then resume it. Works fine after that.

Comment: I just upgraded to 16.04 LTS and started receiving this problem. Very annoying even with the workaround. I hope someday it will be patched...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to go to Systems > Screens (with the lock). Change the time to the screen lock at 1 minute. Then wait until the screen goes black.

Touch the mouse and normally it's ok.

Come back to the last menu to set the previous time to lock again.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found that works for me is to go to 'Displays' then change the resolution to something else (this will fix the colors) and then switch back to your original resolution.